# R, dplyr: How to divide date frame elements by specific elements

Tags: r, dplyr

edit: Solution at the end.

I have a dataframe that contains different variables and the sum of these different variables as a variable called "total". 
I want to add a new column that calculates each variables' share of the "total"-variable.
Example:

```
library(dplyr)

name <- c('A','A', 
          'B','B')
month = c("oct 2018", "nov 2018", 
         "oct 2018",  "nov 2018")

value <- seq(1:length(month))

df = data.frame(name, month, value)

# Create total variable
dfTotal  =
      df%>%
      group_by_("month")%>%
      summarize(value = sum(value, na.rm = TRUE))
dfTotal[["name"]] <-  "Total"
dfTotal = as.data.frame(dfTotal) 

# Add total column to dataframe
df2 = rbind(df, dfTotal)
df2
```

which gives the dataframe

```
   name    month value
1     A oct 2018     1
2     A nov 2018     2
3     B oct 2018     3
4     B nov 2018     4
5 Total nov 2018     6
6 Total oct 2018     4
```

What I want is to produce a new column with the shares of the total for each month in the above dataframe, so that I get something like

```
   name    month value  share
1     A oct 2018     1  0.25 (=1/4)
2     A nov 2018     2  0.33 (=2/6)
3     B oct 2018     3  0.75 (=3/4)
4     B nov 2018     4  0.67 (=4/6)
5 Total nov 2018     6  1.00 (=6/6)
6 Total oct 2018     4  1.00 (=4/4)
```

Does anybody know how I from the first dataframe can produce the last column in the second dataframe?

**Solution:**
Based on tmfmnk's comment, the following solves the problem:

```
df2 = 
  df2 %>% 
  group_by(month) %>% 
  mutate(share = value/max(value))
df2
```

which gives
  name  month    value share

```
  <fct> <fct>    <int> <dbl>
1 A     oct 2018     1 0.25 
2 A     nov 2018     2 0.333
3 B     oct 2018     3 0.75 
4 B     nov 2018     4 0.667
5 Total nov 2018     6 1    
6 Total oct 2018     4 1
```

Comment: I think you can try `df2 %>%
 group_by(month) %>%
 mutate(share = value/max(value))`.

Comment: @tmfmnk : That worked! Thanks a lot! I'll pase it into the original post as a solution!

Comment: @tmfmnk: Write up an answer so this question can be closed.